# TypeScript: Constraint for an object's property to be an array by generic key

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types

Is there a way to write this function such that there is no type casting?

```js
function insert<O extends object, K extends keyof O>(parent: O, key: K) {
  type Item = O[K] extends Array<infer E> ? E : never;
  return (entry: Item) => (key in parent)
    ? (parent[key] as Item[]).push(entry)
    : (parent[key] as Item[]) = [entry];
}
```

I would like to add a constraint, so that `O[K]` is assumed to be an array inside of the function's body. Object-key combinations which don't satisfy this constraint should not typecheck.

### Edit

Based on the answers and my own experimentation I managed to bring it closer to having no casts:

```js
function insert<I, K extends keyof O, O extends { [key in K]?: I[]; }>(parent: O, key: K, item: I) {
  (key in parent)
    ? parent[key].push(item)
    : parent[key] = [item] as O[K];
}
```

However, I still have to use a single cast `as O[K]`, otherwise I get the following error:

```
'I[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'O[K]', but 'O[K]' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'I[]'. ts(2322)
```

### Edit 2:

I've prepared a TypeScript Playground with some example test cases, to make my question less confusing:
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDMBnApgJygHgJIA0iA0ougB5TpgAmqiA1ugJ5zCIDyRHZl1diAN6IA2k2bIkxALoB+AFyI8I6QG5EAXwB8ACgAOAQ0zUoiroxaLiRGFQC2ivAEohAKESId4yYkPGwUE7uHoiyvkYmYizSAIQAdHogqAAWOrbodkEhiIp+keLSiAC8oul2hQb0HCIyqq4arq4oVJjABhDoiACi5AZ2egA2nYLBBoqoUJgoAOZ1HmiKYCB2AEZYKnOIqKgKW5MzG-WNEAgTZIo9fYOdJcJjiABEcAwPRAuiAIxEAEyFGnVNNBYKA6dBEADkaHBRA+3wAzE51AB6JGIZ6AjDYUEQqEQgzgxGIFFkTCYRAAWkQaGQ9CWq3W0jecCgeymYGmKkaKExILBiHB+J+hJCxKwZMpFBgE1QRBWIBZthpYHBLIMSCMmAMzAxwOx-JW0MQ32FHlFpIpiBocHQqGVLMlEy5QKxfPB20NAoJptR6O5utd7ph8JcRNRYot2xprIOjKpzKpyzWmBUQA)

Comment: You could simplify it this way with a different assertion: https://tsplay.dev/WPMMqw

Comment: Not exactly, I would like the function to create an array `[item]` if an array doesn't already exist.

Comment: [This approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXygQN) is how I'd write your code, but I have no idea what you want to do when `key in parent` is false; what type should the array be if the parent object has no key?  See my `k` and `l` examples in the playground link above; what should happen there?  I'm happy to write up an answer but I'd like to see more use cases in the question

Comment: Let's say you have an object `obj` of type `{ a?: number[]; }`, then `insert(obj, 'a', 1)` should turn `{}` into `{ a: [1] }`, or if it receives an object with an array like this `{ a: [1, 2, 3] }` it should push `1` into that array, so you would end up with `{ a: [1, 2, 3, 1] }`. You can implement this trivially with `(key in parent) ? parent[key].push(item) : parent[key] = [item];`, however I am trying to find the best way to type this kind of function, so that it rejects wrong property names (preferably with an autocomplete), and rejects pushing wrong type of an element into array.

Comment: Did you look at [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXygQN)? It does everything you want, as far as I know.  What I *don't* know is how it should act when the type doesn't have a known key, like `insert({}, 'a')`  Please review the playground link and let me know if it works for your needs or if I'm missing something.

Comment: When the object doesn't have a certain key, because it isn't specified in an interface it should be rejected. Only known properties should be allowed, and only those that can hold arrays.

The solution you've posted seems to not work for properties that hold number arrays. I've also removed the part that allows any property, [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WYy22W)

Comment: I've added a playground link with test cases to the original post. It isn't important whether the function is split into *two functions* or if it is a *single function, which accepts three arguments at once*, the important thing is that it is well typed

Comment: So then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wk3z1W) work for your needs?  It is strongly typed and does not require any type assertions.  Let me know if you'd like to see it as an answer. Or if I'm still missing something

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you trying to do via Maps in typescript.
You can easily convert the maps to JSON objects whenever needed

```
function insert<T, K>(parent: Map<T, Array<K>>, key: T) {
  return (entry: K) => (parent.has(key))
    ? (parent.get(key) as K[]).push(entry)
    : parent.set(key, [entry]);
}

const parentObj = new Map<string, Array<string>>([
    ["foo", ["bar", "bas"]]
])

insert(parentObj, "kal")("tar")

console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(parentObj)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function insert<O extends Partial<Record<K, any[]>>, K extends keyof O>(parent: O, key: K) {
  type Item = NonNullable<O[K]>[number];
  return (entry: Item) => (parent[key] ??= ([] as any[] as NonNullable<O[K]>)).push(entry)
}

insert({ foo: [1], bar: 'a' }, 'foo')(1) // ok
insert({ foo: [1], bar: 'a' }, 'foo')('a') // err
insert({ foo: [1], bar: 'a' }, 'bar')(1) // err
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid type casting by using type assertion in its place.

```
function insert<O extends object, K extends keyof O>(parent: O, key: K) {
  type Item = O[K] extends Array<infer E> ? E : never;
  return (entry: Item) => {
    if (key in parent) {
      (parent[key] as Item[]).push(entry);
    } else {
      (parent[key] as unknown) = [entry] as Item[];
    }
  };
}
```

Here, instead of using `(parent[key] as Item[]) = [entry]`, we use `(parent[key] as unknown) = [entry] as Item[]` to perform a type assertion without type casting. This way, the type of `parent[key]` is inferred inherently.